# How does Collections.binarySearch work?

Tags: java, collections

I am trying to understand how Collections.binarySearch work in Java.
I don't quite understand the output I get.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
      // create arraylist       
      ArrayList<String>  arlst=new ArrayList<String> ();


      arlst.add("A");
      arlst.add("D");
      arlst.add("C");
      arlst.add("B");
      arlst.add("E");

      int index=Collections.binarySearch(arlst, "D", Collections.reverseOrder());     

      System.out.println(index);


   }    
}
```

The output of this code is -1.

And when the elements have been inserted at this order

```
      arlst.add("D");
      arlst.add("E");
      arlst.add("C");
      arlst.add("B");
      arlst.add("A");
```

I get 0 as a result. I thought the negative number was a result if the element was not found. Could anybody please clarify the output I receive?

Comment: Do you know how the binary search generally works?

Comment: All useful information for classes jdk usage is very often is the documentation :

"Searches the specified list for the specified object using the binary search algorithm. The list must be sorted into ascending order according to the natural ordering of its elements (as by the sort(List) method) prior to making this call. If it is not sorted, the results are undefined. If the list contains multiple elements equal to the specified object, there is no guarantee which one will be found."

Comment: @davidh, you're quoting the wrong bynarySearch method though. OP is using the one that takes a Comparator as argument.

Comment: @aioobe,
You are right.Sorry. +1
The principle remains the same for both : sorting in the expected order (natural or comparator order) before calling bynarySearch.
The aim of my post is before all to stress on that the official documentation is very often enough for Jdk classes usage and  to read it allows to found a solution to this kind of simple errors.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your data must be sorted according to the given comparator for the binary search to work as intended. (If it's not, the behavior is undefined.)

> The list must be sorted into ascending order according to the specified comparator (as by the `sort(List, Comparator)` method), prior to making this call.

If the data is indeed sorted, the method will return the index of the sought element (if it's found) otherwise `(-(insertion point) - 1)`, as specified in [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch%28java.util.List,%20T%29).

**Example:**

```
// Make sure it's sorted
Collections.sort(arlst, Collections.reverseOrder());

int index=Collections.binarySearch(arlst, "D", Collections.reverseOrder());     

System.out.println(index);  // prints 1
```

Comment: So is it correct that a binary search needs a sorted array to work as expected? Sorry, folks, new to this stuff, trying to figure out how it works.

Comment: Yes. And in this case, since you're using `Collections.reverseOrder` it needs to be sorted as `E`, `D`, `C`, `B`, `A`.

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much! It seemed so confusing but it is actually pretty straightforward.

Comment: @aioobe You Answer is perfect. I might have misunderstood.

Comment: What is the meaning behind `(-(insertion point) - 1)`? What does this value represent? Why was this value chosen?

Comment: @PlsWork, we like the method to return 1) the index where the element was found, or 2) if the element was not found, the index where it should be inserted. To encode both cases in a single `int`, the sign bit is used to differentiate. Positive return value: case 1, negative return value: case 2. Furthermore, since 0 could be a valid insertion point, case 2 is offset with `-1` to avoid any ambiguity. 0 means _element was found at index 0_, and -1 means _element was not found and should be inserted at index 0_.

Answer (score 10):

Just to make it clearer - why the output is **-1**. Yes, you didn't sort it first is a big mistake. But here are some other things to take clear as well.

As @aioobe mentioned in his answer, but he didn't make it clear enough though I think. What does `(-(insertion point) - 1)` mean? Here is what the doc says.

> The index of the search key, if it is contained in the list; otherwise, **(-(insertion point) - 1)**. The insertion point is defined as the point at which the key would be inserted into the list: **the index of the first element greater than the key**, or **list.size()** if all elements in the list are less than the specified key. Note that this guarantees that the return value will be >= 0 if and only if the key is found.

So to make the answer more clear: `-1 = -0 - 1`

What I want to underline here is that the output maybe `-2` or `-3` or whatever. Because if **all elements in the list are less than the specified key**, the output will be `-list.size() - 1`.

Answer (score 2):

```
■ Searches are performed using the binarySearch() method.
■ Successful searches return the int index of the element being searched.
■ Unsuccessful searches return an int index that represents the insertion point. The insertion point is the place in the collection/array where the element would be inserted to keep the collection/array properly sorted.
        * Return values and 0 indicate successful searches
        * Negative numbers to indicate insertion points
        * The first available insertion point is -1. Therefore,the  actual insertion point is represented as (-(insertion point) -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the inner workings of the binarySearch method:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package binarysearch;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;


public class BinarySearch {

    static ArrayList<String> strings;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String sample = "a quick brown fox jumped right over the lazy dog while an active lion was nowhere in sight";
        String[] simpleArray = sample.split(" ");
        strings = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(simpleArray));
        Collections.sort(strings);
        // Enter a search string; here it is "lazy"
        binarySearch(strings, "lazy");
        System.out.println("");
        // Print the Array contents for convenience
        printArrayList(strings);
    }
    
    static void printArrayList(ArrayList<String> strings) {
        int i = 0;
        for (String s: strings) {
            i++;
            System.out.println(i + s );
        }
    }
    
    
    
    static void binarySearch (ArrayList<String> strings, String searchString) {
        boolean debug = true;
        int low = 0;
        int high = strings.size();
        int mid = 0;
        while (low <= high) {
            // The > symbol marks the hits before search is concluded
            System.out.print(">");
            mid = (high + low) / 2;
            
            int comparison = strings.get(mid).compareToIgnoreCase(searchString);
            if (comparison > 0) {
                high = mid - 1;
            } else if (comparison < 0) {
                low = mid + 1;
            } else {
                int temp = mid;
                System.out.println("Found '" + searchString + "' at: " + (temp + 1) );
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```